# gRPC vs JSON-RPC API?

Tags: json-rpc

gRPC is modern high-performance RPC framework. Using gRPC is certainly than the use of JSON RPC for communication between geth nodes and the clients such as web3. Is gRPC is part of the Ethereum roadmap?